# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable while reading list in python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function which gets all the elements from list to another list, but sometimes my list can be None. I tried below code with checking if not None.
Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance.

```
from typing import  List
fruits = ["lemon", "pear", "watermelon", "tomato"]
food = None
def check(items:List[str]):
  c = ["apple","banana",
      *[value for value in items if items is not None]]
  print(*c)

check(fruits)
check(food)
```

Comment: You mean `c = ["apple", "banana", *[value for value in items or []]]`?

Comment: checking if items is not none is done too late: you're already iterating on it

Comment: or simply `c = ["apple", "banana", *[items or []]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change inner unpacking to list extension/concatenation with `or` check:

```
def check(items:List[str]):
  c = ["apple","banana"] + (items or [])
  print(*c)

check(fruits)
check(food)
```

---

```
apple banana lemon pear watermelon tomato
apple banana
```